# Mi Receiver de la alarma no ejecuta el servicio

Tags: android, android-studio, servicio, notificaciones, broadcastreceiver

Estoy llamando creando una alarma de esta manera. (y lo hace bien)
La alarma se inicia desde un fragment, con un botón.. y noto que allí no esta el problema. Coloco parte del codigo donde lo inicio.

```
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getContext().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext().getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
                alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext().getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

                // Set the alarm to start at 8:30 a.m.
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                //calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
                //calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

                // setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
                // 20 minutes.
                alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                        1000 * 60 * 2, alarmIntent);
```

Tengo creado el receiver, el cual es llamado correctamente por la alarma. Cada dos minuto lo llama y noto que se ejecuta.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service1 = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
        service1.setData((Uri.parse("custom://" + System.currentTimeMillis())));
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, service1 );
        Log.d("ALARMA", " ALARM RECEIVED!!!");
```

Incluso veo que se muestra el log.
El problema que tengo es que no se ejecuta el servicio llamado NotificationService.
Probé de muchas maneras pero no logro ejecutarlo.

```
public class NotificationService  extends IntentService {
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    Notification notification;

    // GPS
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    boolean isGPSEnable = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnable = false;
    double latitude,longitude;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    Location location;
    //Location mLastLocation;
    //mLastLocation = new Location(provider);

    public NotificationService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public NotificationService() {
        super("SERVICE");
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent2) {
        Log.d("ALARMA", " Dentro de NotificationService");
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.app_name);
        Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        Resources res = this.getResources();
        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "A) Latgps",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i( "msg", "Servicio reiniciado");

        String message = getString(R.string.new_notification);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            final int NOTIFY_ID = 0; // ID of notification
            String id = NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID; // default_channel_id
            String title = NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID; // Default Channel
            PendingIntent pendingIntent;
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
            NotificationManager notifManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            if (notifManager == null) {
                notifManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            }
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = notifManager.getNotificationChannel(id);
            if (mChannel == null) {
                mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, title, importance);
                mChannel.enableVibration(true);
                mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
                notifManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, id);
            mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name)).setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)   // required
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_notification))
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(soundUri)

                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            Notification notification = builder.build();
            notifManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);

            startForeground(1, notification);

        } else {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_notification))
                    .setSound(soundUri)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name)).setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                    .setContentText(message).build();
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        }

    }
```

Que me puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 0):

Estaba todo bien al final......
Me falto declarar el servicio en el manifest...
Esta resuelto
FUnciona...
De paso el que necesita el codigo lo puede usar